# System Status page notifications

Tags: upgrade

After upgrading CiviCRM on Drupal 7 to 5.22.1 (from 5.21), the system status page says:

> The site is running 5.21.0. Additional patches are available:
>
> - 5.21.1 (2020-01-10): Fix recent regressions involving "Enable multiple bulk emails" and "Payment Summary" table.
> - 5.21.2 (2020-01-23): Fix recent regressions involving contact date-filters, certain receipts, certain smart-groups, and localized installation."

An attempt to run the database upgrade again returns the error: *The database has already been updated to 5.22.1.*

Does this mean the upgrade did not succeed? If it did, how can the system status page be updated?

Help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Maybe the cache didn't get cleared and it's showing an outdated message. I think it caches those. I'd try clearing cache at administer - system settings - cleanup caches.

Comment: The issue still persists even after clearing the cache.

Comment: I've seen this previously where the System Status page hasn't recognised the upgrade but I don't recall the reason why.  What version does it show in the page footers?

Comment: The page footer shows 5.22.1

Comment: try manually running the "Update Check" scheduled job.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suspect you didn't actually update CiviCRM, as far as CiviCRM is concerned.

1. Perhaps the old code is still kicking around and accessible to your CMS (e.g. perhaps you left it in, maybe renamed?).
2. Perhaps you have a very aggressive opcache that hasn't recognized the new code yet.
3. Perhaps you didn't install the new CiviCRM codebase that you thought you did (I've done that before often enough ...).